# need help on java swing layout

Tags: java, swing

Below are my code to add label and textfield.
i want to add it such that its [label] [textfield] in 2 column

i know i can do it by using gridlayout but the number of rows need to be fixed, hence is there another method to add it such that no matters how many [label] [textfield] i add in, it will be 2 column

the picture shows the expected view

but currently it is [label] [textfield] [label2] [textfield2] [label3] [textfield3]

```
  public WizardPage page1() {
           WizardPage page1 = new WizardPage("1", "Page 1") {
               {
                   JTextField txt1 = new JTextField();
                   JTextField txt2 = new JTextField();
                   JTextField txt3 = new JTextField();
                   JTextField txt4 = new JTextField();

                   txt1.setName("text1");
                   txt2.setName("text2");
                   txt3.setName("text3");
                   txt4.setName("text4");

                   txt1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
                   txt2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
                   txt3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
                   txt4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));

                   add(new JLabel("text1"));
                   add(txt1);
                   add(new JLabel("text2"));
                   add(txt2);
                   add(new JLabel("text3"));
                   add(txt3);
                   add(new JLabel("text4"));
                   add(txt4);
               }
           };
           return page1;
       }



>    public WizardPage(String title, String description){
>        
>        PropertyConfigurator.configure("config/log4j.properties");
>        log = Logger.getLogger(WizardPage.class);
>       
>       _title = title;
>       _description = description;
>       
> 
>     setLayout(new FlowLayout()); );


      addContainerListener(new WPContainerListener());
      this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
   }
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835198/positioning-of-components-how-to-place-a-few-buttons-center-screen-same-size/12837118#12837118 Use BoxLayout, check my other answers to find more examples

Comment: but doesnt boxlayout make everything in 1 column?

Comment: You can nest layouts, so `BoxLayout` can be used. If you want to use `GridLayout`, use the constructor as: `new GridLayout(0, 2)`. That sets the number of columns to 2, and rows are added as needed.

Comment: but if i have 4 row i have to change to GridLayout(4, 2). cant it be more dynamic such that whatever number of rows it will always be 2 column

Comment: Please read what I wrote: *That sets the number of columns to 2, and rows are added as needed*. Setting rows to 0 gives the dynamic behaviour you want.

Comment: @kiheru - you should put your comments in an answer.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer How to use GridLayout: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Comment: @newbieprogrammer absolutely not, boxlayout don't make everything in 1 column, with the correct nesting you can make almost everything you want, please read my link and you will be cleared on the argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to have unspecified number of rows in a grid is to use `GridLayout` with 0 as the row count:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
```

This will result in 2 columns, and rows being added as needed. The downside of `GridLayout` is that the labels and text fields  will have the same width, which may not be what you want.

Another easy approach is nesting layouts: you could place each label + text field combination to a JPanel, and then continue adding those panels to a vertical [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) as needed. This neither, is flawless, and can result in a layout like:

```
label | text
-----------------
long label | text
```

If you need a grid that can make the columns and rows different width, investigate other grid based layouts: [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) comes with the standard library, and is capable of such grids, but is a bit complicated to use. If you find yourself making a lot of such layouts, consider using a third party layout manager, such as [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: thanks.. i miss understood ur answer and i didnt know 0 is dynamic number of rows